# Adjective to Define "Key" Features

Tags: adjectives, software

My company has released a big upgrade to our flagship software.

There are 5 key features that would motivate the user to upgrade.

Is there an adjective that is commonly used to describe those features?

"Motivating?" "Big?" "Key?"

Comment: 'Headline features' might be worth considering.

Comment: *Mind-blowing, death-defying, life-changing, apocalyptic, bet-the-ranch-on, earth-shattering, never-before-seen features!* Or maybe just *nice*.

Comment: When a printed description of the new product becomes available for the consumer, the new features will probably appear as "bullet-points" - You can refer to them as: "The Five Bullets."

Comment: Is there a reason that 'key' itself can't be used?  If not, then that's quite common in this context.

Comment: @Robin: OP's example actually *defines* the exact sense intended *(features that would motivate the user to upgrade)*. But in a less explicitly "self-defining" context, ***key** features* might actually mean *features which are essential **now**, in order for us to be able to introduce an even better version next year*. That's to say they might be "key" to the future plans of the software producers, but of no significance whatsoever to current users (who may be completely unaware of them, since they don't affect current performance or UI).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It does, but I was unsure from the question as to the context in which the adjective itself will be used.  e.g. Promotional material or internal presentation? OP themself suggested 'key' as an option but there's an implied reason as to why it can't be used.  Your answer of 'must-have' is good by the way, although personally I always feel like I'm being sold **at** rather than **to** when this is used.  I'd maintain that 'key' can be a consumer-level word, as in [this example](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/phones/mobile-phones/iphone-6-plus-1264566/review/2).

Comment: @Robin: I see your point, but you could reasonably say something like *"I'm looking for a new [HTPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_theater_PC) on eBay. My must-have features are silent running, HDMI output, and wireless Internet access"*. The reality of the *must-have* usage is it's based on the *potential buyers'* requirements, not what some marketing man *thinks* they might want, even though it's probably more common among sellers than buyers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: True, true.  Have an upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *There are 5 **must-have** features that would motivate the user to upgrade*.

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/must-have[adjective])...

> **must-have**, adjective: *- impossible to do without*
>    Synonyms: *all-important, critical, imperative, indispensable, integral, must-have, necessary, necessitous, needed, needful, required, requisite, vital*

Answer (score 2):

> There are five **Unique** features that would motivate the user to
>   upgrade.

The [unique selling proposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_selling_proposition) (USP) or unique selling point is a marketing concept first proposed as a theory to explain a pattern in successful advertising campaigns of the early 1940s.

The USP states that such campaigns made **unique propositions** to customers that convinced them to switch brands. (Wiki)

> There are five **Unique** **propositions** that would motivate the user to
>   upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

One phrase that comes to mind is ***new shining features*** (or similar along these lines — gleaming, radiant, etc.). This is, in fact, a collocation similar to the one used by StackExchange at the moment to advertise its new version of user profiles.

Moreover, if there happen to be five of them, one can perhaps contrive for a simile to five digits on a hand, or so.